# How do I find the row with max length of one column grouping on another column in pure python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I need some sql like functionality with preferably with pure python and not panda. Need to group on the second column and get the column with largest length of column one.
**A slight change in the requirement. My requirement is to get the tag whose length is just less than the max length.
step 1: Get the max count of / in second column.
Step 2: Return the tag whose count of / in second column is one less than the one from step 1**
My List has:

```
 ['MYDATA_FILE_XT', '/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XT_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XT_ROW_STATUS', '/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS', 'string']
['XX', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW_CURRENCY_CODE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['YY', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW_EXCESS_AMOUNT', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['LM', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW_USD_EQUIVALENT', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
```

**New Expectation :**
['MYDATA_FILE_XT_ROW']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list is in a variable named `data`, this should populate a variable, `cleaned` with your expected results:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

cleaned = []
for key, values in groupby(data, itemgetter(1)):
    cleaned += [reduce(lambda x, y: x if len(x[0]) > len(y[0]) else y, values)]
```

Comment: Thanks joeb. This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary storing the largest length path for the second column and convert it to list later

```
for row in rows:
 try:
    length=len(result[row[1]])
    if(len(row[0])>length):
        result[row[1]]=row[0]
 except:
    result[rows[1]]=row[0]
```